# Display Random Data From Table

Tags: php, mysql, forms

I have looked around the site before posting this but nothing seems to make sense. I have a form that submits information to a table. The for has three fields: $name, $link and $itunes. The MySQL table has 3 columns and I'm looking to pull a name, link and itunes at random and display it on a page. I currently have no code, other than the form that submits to the database. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: So you want to match all the fields you have from the form and then display a random row that matches?

Comment: You want to fetch one random row on every refresh or you wanted to fetch them all and wanted to show them randomly on your page without refresh ??

Comment: Cheers for the reply. Sumit, I would like to display a random row everytime someone refreshes that page. So it will show the $name, $link and the $itunes (iTunes Link)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the SQL query you may find useful:

```
SELECT name, link, table FROM mytable ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT * FROM `table` ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 0,1;
```

This will fetch any random data from mysql.

Procedural way:

```
<?php
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");

/* check connection */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

$query = "SELECT * FROM `table` ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 0,1";

if ($result = mysqli_query($link, $query)) {

    /* fetch associative array */
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        printf ("%s (%s)\n", $row["Name"], $row["CountryCode"]);
    }

    /* free result set */
    mysqli_free_result($result);
}

/* close connection */
mysqli_close($link);
?>
```

Comment: Thanks, this works on the MySQL back-end. I'm looking to now get that on  a web-page using PHP? Any ideas?

Comment: call this query using PDO or mysqli in php, fetch data using fetch_assoc and display in php.

Comment: @ItsJoeTurner have added example for reference, its from php.net nothing new.

Comment: Thanks.. is there a way of saving the data to a variable to use on the page anywhere instead of just printing it?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15661/discussion-between-itsjoeturner-and-amitchhajer)

Comment: ya save as $variable = $row["Name"]

Answer (score 0):

With that table structure you could use ORDER BY rand() but it's too slow.
If you had an id column you could get the last row(ie. SELECT id FROM table_name ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1) and then with php get a random value (rand(1,$max) ) and then use a select query to get that row via that random id. You'd have to run a check that this id actually exists in case you removed it.